# SF Symbols always render with a slightly different size

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, storyboard, sf-symbols

I'm experiencing a strange issue with my UIKit app. I have a `UITableView` that contains a `UICollectionView`. The `UITableView` gets reloaded every few seconds, but after each reload, the size of the SF Symbols inside the `UICollectionView` cells changes slightly, as you can see in this example (I've set the reload timer to 1 second for demonstration purposes).

[image: Demo]

I'm not sure if this issue is caused by my unusual table view/collection view configuration or if it's an Apple bug. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

**Here's the relevant code:**

**This is inside my `ViewController`:**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

...

productsCollectionView.reloadData()
return cell
}


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "verbindungCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! verbindungCollectionViewCell
    
    if legArray[tempIndexPathFromTableView.row][0][indexPath.row] is PublicLeg {
        //Public Leg
        var tempPublicLeg = legArray[tempIndexPathFromTableView.row][0][indexPath.row] as! PublicLeg
        cell.serviceLabel.text = tempPublicLeg.line.label
        cell.serviceImageView.image = getProductSymbol(productType: productToTransportType(product: tempPublicLeg.line.product!), designPack: .automatic)
        cell.setCancelled(tempPublicLeg.isCancelled)
        if tempPublicLeg.isCancelled == true {
            
        }
    } else {
        //Individual Leg (Walk)
        var tempIndLeg = legArray[tempIndexPathFromTableView.row][0][indexPath.row] as! IndividualLeg
        cell.serviceImageView.image = getProductSymbol(productType: .walk, designPack: .automatic)
        cell.serviceLabel.text = tempIndLeg.departure.getDistanceText(CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(tempIndLeg.arrival.coord?.lat ?? 0)/1000000, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(tempIndLeg.arrival.coord?.lon ?? 0)/1000000))
    }
    return cell
}
```

**This is the function that returns the SF Symbols:**

```
func getProductSymbol(productType: TransportType, designPack: DesignPack) -> UIImage? {

...Determinate color, symbol etc...

    if colorType == .singleColor {
    let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(hierarchicalColor: colors[0])
    let image = UIImage(systemName: symbolName, withConfiguration: config)?.withRenderingMode(.automatic)
    
    return image
} else if colorType == .multipleColor {
    let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: colors)
    let image = UIImage(systemName: symbolName, withConfiguration: config)?.withRenderingMode(.automatic)
    return image
} else {
    return nil
}
}
```

**And here is my `UIViewController` in Storyboard:**

[image]

Thank you all in advantage.

Comment: You have a ***LOT*** going on there -- so, two quick suggestions... 1: use your `SymbolConfiguration` to explicitly set the size of the SF Symbol, and 2: Try to reproduce the issue under much, much simpler conditions. Start with a `UIImageView` by itself, where you are updating the image every second. If it doesn't show the same sizing problem, make it a subview of another view. Keep adding *minor* complexity changes until you have code that clearly and easily reproduces the problem so it can be debugged from there.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, I'm unable to adjust the size of the SFSymbols because I'm already using the color attribute. As far as I know, it's only possible to modify one aspect of the symbol at a time.

Comment: Okay, i reproduced the issue successfully and it was the constraints, I am going to  find a way to fix it.

Comment: Victor -- if you found constraint issue(s), then sure, you want to fix that. However... you can certainly apply both color and size (and other) attributes to SFSymbols - take a look at this Apple docs page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/configuring_and_displaying_symbol_images_in_your_ui

Comment: Oh my god! I made several approaches but never thought of this. I now „fixed“ it by simply removing the constraints of the label und ImageView inside the CollectionViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

First I wouldn't place `productsCollectionView.reloadData()` within `UITableView, cellForRowAt`. This will cause the collectionView to do a full layout reload foreach item in the tableView.

Also try putting a breakpoint in `getProductSymbol`, does it get called over and over again, even after the datas been reloaded?

If so that's the problem.